# how to use callbackonoffline plugin openfire

Tags: android, openfire

how to use callbackonoffline plugin of openfire. Please check https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/tree/master/src/plugins/callbackOnOffline and URL is "http://localhost:8080/user/offline/callback/url which is no working.

Comment: callbackonoffline plugin is already disscussed here, hopefully it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376523/send-notification-using-openfire-xmpp-server-android-using-callbackonoffline#comment68096548_40376523

Comment: Thanks shoaib .I have paste the callbackonoffline.jar file into plugins directory of openfire but still URL is not working.I can see offline users message are store into ofoffline table of my mysql table. I need to get that message to my android mobile device by notification without using fcm or gcm.I want to do with callbackonoffline.jar.Can you help me for that i am trying from last 1 week.

Comment: To install plugins without admin panel, you have BOTH copy the jar and unjar in the same directory the same jar.

Comment: Can you please tell me details step for that this    
callbackonoffline?

Answer (score 1):

For use of callbackonoffline plug-in you must install this plugin
Best way for install plugin is :

1. need to do is login to Openfire server as admin
2. go to tab "Plugins"
3. there you will find "Available Plugins" and you can one click to
   install it without downloading anything.

And then goto system properties
add your callback link in 'plugin.callback_on_offline.url' property.